# SaaS application structure in YII using separate database

Tags: yii

I need create a SaaS application structure in YII Framework using separate database, but the examples in the web are using a single database. Any information or handbook will be welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a second DB by adding it to your `main.php` ex:

```
    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'schemaCachingDuration' => 3600,
        'enableProfiling' => true,
    ),

    'db2'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database2',
        'class'=>'CDbConnection',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'schemaCachingDuration' => 3600,
        'enableProfiling' => true,
    ),
```

Then you can set the `getDbConnection()` method inside the active records that are to use this second db. I would suggest making a parent class extending from CActiveRecord with this code and then extending that.

It should contain:

```
public static $db2;

public function getDbConnection()
{
  if(self::$db2!==null)
     return self::$db2;
  else
  {
     self::$db2=Yii::app()->db2;
     if(self::$db2 instanceof CDbConnection)
     {
        self::$db2->setActive(true);
        return self::$db2;
     }
     else
        throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','Active Record requires a "db" CDbConnection application component.'));
  }
}
```